# How to load a big text file efficiently in python

Tags: python, file, search, file-io, full-text-search

I have a text file containing 7000 lines of strings. I got to search for a specific string based upon few params.

Some are saying that the below code wouldn't be efficient (speed and memory usage).

```
f = open("file.txt")
data = f.read().split() # strings as list
```

1. First of all, if don't even make it as a list, how would I even start searching at all?
2. Is it efficient to load the entire file? If not, how to do it?
3. To filter anything, we need to search for that we need to read it right!

A bit confused

Comment: as long as it fits in memory reading it all at once is probably the fastest(if that is your measure of efficiency) ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I am looking for speed and memory efficiency. A middle solution would be best.

Comment: Off topic, is Dennis Ritchie your real name? Using the name of a dead person seems otherwise tasteless to me.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer I am no dennis ritchie (the C guy)

Comment: A possible problem with your code is that a file could be too large to fit in your memory, @Ashwini Chaudhary provided a solution that is more memory efficient. On the other point: I don't think that iterating over a file is a huge speed reduction.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary's solution is actually both more memory efficient and gets better speed than loading it all at once (based  on %timeit results)  (which actually was suprising to me...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iterate over each line of the file, without storing it. This will make for program memory Efficient.

```
with open(filname) as f:
   for line in f:
      if "search_term" in line:
           break
```

Comment: this if memory usage is your measure of efficiency? right? but if your talking computational speed its probably faster to load at once ? ... (although the speed difference is likely trivial) ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I think in terms of speed as well as memory this should do it, instead of storing the whole file at once.

Comment: but, iterating over 7000 lines is really big thing. isn't it

Comment: @DennisRitchie if you're filtering is based on each line of the file, then it's not a good idea to store the whole file.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Well, rather than using a linear search, can I use Binary search using file object?

Comment: it will exit early once it finds a match

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary oh your right ... i made it so there would be no match (force worst case) and this method was 9 us faster per timeit than loading whole file at once ... suprised me ... (this was using a file with 1000 chars per line and 7000 lines

Comment: @DennisRitchie well to do binary search you need to load the whole data first in a list. and as you said that the file is huge then it might use a whole lot of memory, making it memory inefficient.

Comment: Got it.. what you are saying.

Comment: @JoranBeasley thanks for actually testing, it might be because loading the whole file actually iterates over whole file first, and then the filtering part repeats the same process, so actually is kind of `O(n^3) `comapared to `O(n^2)` in my case.

Comment: *The solution actually blown my mind* I never thought a linear search would do the job. Fantastic! I was thinking in the lines of Binary - Merge and the Prof was pointing memory thing. haha. I think this is an example worth for students to look at! don't you think?

Comment: @DennisRitchie Ignoring the `in` part the linear search will take `O(n) `time here while binary search will take `O(nlogn)`, because you need to load the whole file first into a list, i.e a `O(n)` operation and then binary search takes `logn`